# Typo in the FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed

From [the FAQ](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/faq):

[image: Screenshot of a possible typo in the Web Applications FAQ]

---

Shouldn't that be *application*?

Comment: I hope Jeff Atwood will not [come after me with a big S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean? It says "application" :)